# Mobile API Paypal Delayed Payments

Tags: ios, paypal

Needed some help. We are working on building in Paypal delayed chained payments into an iOS app. I am not seeing an api method for this transaction in the mobile sdk. I was wondering if you guys know the best way to implement a Paypal delayed chained transaction in an iOS app?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It would be what they're calling the [Mobile Payments Library](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL).  Basically, it's just making use the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) platform.

For Chained payments it's really just a matter of generating a [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) request that includes a primary receiver and one or more secondary receivers.  You'll need to set the action to PAY_PRIMARY in your Pay request in order to do a delayed chained payment.

That would send the total amount to the primary receiver, and then at some point later you can trigger [ExecutePayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/) to process the secondary payments, which would send from the primary receiver's account to the secondary receivers.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. We have been using the API, but our problem is to execute the second part of a 2 part delayed transaction. We are building a marketplace app where we want to automate payments to secondary recipients(sellers) based on a specific user action within our app (when the buyer acknowledges receipt of what has been bought). We are not finding a specific way to do this unfortunately.

Comment: I updated the answer with some extra details for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn’t find any way to define the actionType on the advanced payment object, and the documentation (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_iphone.pdf) doesn’t mention this possibility, even though it’s supported by the REST api, but not in the Mobile SDK.

Comment: Well if you just generate the Pay request on your own you could set whatever parameters you need to.

Comment: I have same issue. PAY_PRIMARY  not found anywhere in paypal MPL library .  Can you  give little bit code to create Pay request?